# Retrieving Data from File in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have created an application in which i have successfully write the details in the file. But while accessing the file from the application i am getting the following exceptoin:

[image]

Following is my class:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Following is my code to write and read and file:

```
private async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        details.Name = TxtName.Text;
        details.Course = TxtCouse.Text;
        details.City = TxtCity.Text;
        await SaveAsync();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(string));
    }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder localfolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Storage Application", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile sampleFile = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("UserDetails", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        using(IOutputStream outstream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserDetails));
            serializer.WriteObject(outstream.AsStreamForWrite(), details);
            await outstream.FlushAsync();
        }
        await RestoreDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task RestoreDataAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder localfolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Storage Application");
        StorageFile sampleFile = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("UserDetails");
        IRandomAccessStream inStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(UserDetails));
        var Details = (UserDetails)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
        inStream.Dispose();
        TblName.Text = details.Name;
        TblCourse.Text = details.Course;
        TblCity.Text = details.City;
    }
```

I am new in creating Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your SaveAsync() method, You opened the StorageFile of sampleFile, but havn't disposed it. Try to add `sampleFile.Dispose();` after you used it.

Comment: i am not able to access the sampleFile.Dispose(). Dispose() is not exist.